# Save as shapefile error in QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, error

When I try to save a specific vector shapefile (line) as another  vector shapefile line also (Backup Copy) in QGIS version 2.10 or 2.18.3 I get the following error message:

> Export to vector file failed. 
>   Error: Feature write errors: Feature creation error (OGR error:
>   Attempt to write non-linestring (POINT) geometry to ARC type
>   shapefile.) Only 236 of 237 features written.

I think there is a geometry problem but I do not know how to isolate the problem or how to troubleshoot the error. Does anybody have any suggestions on how to fix this?

This is the same as the export to shapefile tool in ArcGIS

Comment: Do you have any null or empty geometry in your table?

Comment: This looks like a vertex collapse issue. Shapefile lines require at least two disparate vertices.  The "error" seems more of a warning.

Answer (score 5):

You can install the `Vertices Counter` plugin to see if you have a one-point line feature in your layer.

Additionally, you can create a virtual field of type `real` and content `$length`, and let the whole attribute table sort by that. You should then have a zero-length feature at the top or bottom of the list.